# refreshing the list view on dragging down or up like gmail or facebook

Tags: android, android-listview

In my android app i have a listview.which is populated from a json file which I am getting after sending a rest api to server.
now I want to show only say 20 items in the list at a time.(only 20 item will be fetched from the server at a time)
now say more item to display i want to drag the list view down to populate more.
like gmail android app.

Can any body tell me the correct procedure to do this.How do I achieve this type of feature with visual effect.

please help

Comment: Feature is named `pull-to-refresh` and you can find a lot of libraries providing this feature. eg. https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh

Answer (score 0):

Chris Banes ( thethe same guy that implemented the best pull to refresh component for android) also implemented the GMail like Pull To Refresh.

You can find it [here](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh)

Note that this project is still under development so the current API may change.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way:
You could create a custom component that extends ListView widget. 
In this custom component you can implement your logic when user touches the screen. So you have to override `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)`.
Something like that

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    //System.out.println("First ["+this.getFirstVisiblePosition()+"]");

    float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            if ( ( y - startY) > THRESHOLD && STATE_REFRESH_ENABLED && !STATE_REFRESHING ) {
                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.onRefresh();
                    STATE_REFRESHING = true;
                }
            }
        }
        break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            startY = y;
            STATE_REFRESH_ENABLED = getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0; // We are on the first element so we can enable refresh
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            STATE_REFRESHING = false;
        }

    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

And implement a listener interface to get notified when it is time to refresh the listview.
You can give a look at my [blog](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/06/android-listview-pull-to-refresh.html) where i describe in details how to create this component.